# Django urlpatterns - NoReverseMatch at... Reverse for '' with no arguments not found

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am building a modal form in Django that would allow the user to edit the details of an existing record. Specifically, in the `paper_detail.html`, there is a button that the user can click on, which would then load the specific paper in a modal form via ajax.

Once the paper is loaded into the modal form, the user can edit it.

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/paper/796134/`, I ran into the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /paper/796134/
Reverse for 'edit_paper' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

This is very puzzling to me  because I expect it to go to `paper_detail`.

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('paper/<int:pk>/', views.paper_detail, name='paper_detail'),
     url('', views.load_paper, name='load_paper'),
     url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.edit_paper, name='edit_paper'),
     path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

What I found is that if I remove the `(?P<pk>\d+)` from the `edit_paper` pattern, the page loads fine. (i.e.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/paper/796134/` loads correctly if 
`url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.edit_paper, name='edit_paper'),` becomes
`url(r'^edit/$', views.edit_paper, name='edit_paper'),`

This would be problem solved but I believe I actually need to have `(?P<pk>\d+)` in the `edit_paper` pattern. This is 
because I need to pass the `pk` of the paper back to the `edit_paper` function by including `{{object.pk}}` as a parameter in form action.

Please advise what is the best course of action! thanks a lot!!

This is the `edit_paper_modal.html` template where I pass the `pk` of the paper back to the `edit_paper` function to save updated information about the paper in the database.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <form action="{% url 'search:edit_paper' %} pk={{object.pk}}" method="post" class="form" >
      {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"> 
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Paper</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{form|crispy}}
                {{ form.media }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save changes" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the ajax function in `paper_detail.html` that would call the `load_paper` function to load the paper in the modal form:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    var pk = $(this).data('pid')
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  });
  $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
    var modal = $(this)
    var pk = $(this).data('pid')
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: {'pk': pk},
        url: "{% url 'search:load_paper' %}",
        context: document.body,
        error: function(response, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        modal.html(response);
    });
  });
});
</script>

## the button in the paper_detail.html

<button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" id="myBtn" data-pid={{paper.pk}}>Edit Paper Details</button>
```

To load the record in the modal form, I have a `load_paper` function in `views.py`:

```
def load_paper(request):
    pk = request.GET.get('pk')
    object = get_object_or_404(Paper, pk = pk)
    form = PaperForm(instance=object)
    return render(request, 'edit_paper_modal.html', {
        'object': object,
        'form': form,
        })

def edit_paper(request, pk=None):
    template_name = 'edit_paper_modal.html'
    if request.POST:
        paper = get_object_or_404(Paper, pk = pk)
        form = PaperForm(instance=paper, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'paper_detail.html', {'paper': paper})

def paper_detail(request, pk):
    paper = get_object_or_404(Paper, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'paper_detail.html', {'paper': paper})
```

EDIT:

Including `paper_detail.html`

```
{% if paper %}

        <h4>Details for <b>{{ paper.title }}</b></h4>
        <!-- <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}

        </form> -->
        <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" id="myBtn" data-pid={{paper.pk}}>Edit Paper Details</button>
        {% csrf_token %}

       <!-- Modal -->
       <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" > {% csrf_token %}
         <div class="modal-dialog">
         </div>
       </div>

        <p>Status: {{paper.get_status_display }} </p>
        <a href="#" class="like_button" data-pid="{{ paper.pk }}"> <span class="like_span fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
            <strong id="like_count_{{ paper.pk }}">{{paper.likes}} </strong> </a>
            <p>Abstract:
                <br>{{ paper.abstract }}</p>

        {% endif %}


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<form>` you closed to `{% url ... %}` tag too early. Now it says:

```
<form action="{% url 'search:edit_paper' %} pk={{object.pk}}">
```

But you should replace this with:

```
<form action="{% url 'search:edit_paper' pk=object.pk %}">
```

Note that in a template tag, you should *not* use double curly brackets (`{{ ... }}`) for variables.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!! I fixed that but I still got the error `NoReverseMatch at /paper/796134/
Reverse for 'edit_paper' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']` when I load `http://127.0.0.1:8000/paper/796134/`

Comment: @OnyiL: usually Django also shows the part of the template where it goes wrong. There is likely another case in your template with more or less, the same error.

Comment: @OnyiL: please search the template for other `edit_paper` urls, and try to restart the webserver.

Comment: I am looking quite hard but couldn't seem to find other `edit_paper`  urls that are at fault. On the other hand, in looking at the traceback, it says the following: ``` Template error:
In template /Users/onyi/Documents/jikan/jikan/templates/base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'edit_paper' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)/']``` Is that pointing to the same error that you said or should I examine my base.html more closely?

Comment: Yes, did you write it like `{% url 'search:edit_paper' pk=object.pk %}` so with `pk=` *in* the `{% url ... %}` block?

Comment: yes, this is how my form looks like in `edit_paper_modal.html`:
```<form action="{% url 'search:edit_paper' pk=object.pk %}" method="post" class="form" >```

Comment: Let me examine other templates too?

Comment: @OnyiL: that's definitely a good idea. Perhaps it is also worth restarting the server, since sometimes templates are cached.

Comment: So no luck with restarting (I am on development server) and checking other templates - but going through the traceback, it seems to suggest that there is something wrong with my `paper_detail` function: `def paper_detail(request, pk):
    paper = get_object_or_404(Paper, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'paper_detail.html', {'paper': paper}) `

Comment: But your `load_paper` uses `request.GET`?

Comment: `load_paper` is called by the ajax, shouldn't it automatically use `GET`?

Comment: @OnyiL: if the id is dynamic, usually yes, if it is static, you can just encode it in the URL. What error do you get exactly?

Comment: yeah the id is dynamic. this is the error: ```NoReverseMatch at /paper/796134/
Reverse for 'edit_paper' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)/']```

Comment: Well the only `edit_paper` in a template in your question is the one that I mentioned in the answer, so there might still be one somewhere hidden (or perhaps you did not save the template properly).

Comment: After I removed some commented out code, it somehow loads now! thank you so much for your patience!!